# How to send mails to users from office group mailID using NodeJS & nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have a scenario like when users register with their identities , I would have to send them activation link for verification.
     I dont want to send mails through GMAIL/YAHOO/LIVE etc. I can create a group mailID (xxx-support@yyy.com) from my office. 
     My problem is i dont know how to set up this process. What should i do .. Do i have to set up any SMTP servers ??? If yes ,, my question would be how to create smtp servers ??

```
 Could you please help to get away from this bottleneck ??  

  smtpConfig = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
service: 'OfficeMailBox',
auth: {
user: "xxx-support@yyy.com",
pass: "yourpasswordgoeshere"
}
});

 mailOpts = {
from: req.body.name + ' &lt;' + req.body.email + '&gt;',
to: 'me@gmail.com', //replace it with id you want to send multiple must be separated by     ,
subject: 'contact form',
text: req.body.message
};

smtpConfig.sendMail(mailOpts, function (error, response) {
//Email not sent
if (error) {
res.end("Email send Falied");
}
//email send sucessfully
else {
res.end("Email send sucessfully");
}
});
```

Regards
Ram

Comment: did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom smtp server address:

```
smtpConfig = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
  host: 'smtp.yourserver.com',//<----
  auth: {
     user: "xxx-support@yyy.com",
     pass: "yourpasswordgoeshere"
  }
});
```